# Passing tuple to a Python function

Tags: python, tuples

I know that there has been a bit of discussion about passing a tuple to a function; I checked all of them but couldn't solve my problem. So here is the problem. I am trying to pass two tuples into a function and do calculations on them. Here is a sample:

```
c=(2,3)
d=(4,5)

def func1((a(0),a(1)),(b(0),b(1))):
    return(a(0)*b(1))
```

I also tried

```
c=(2,3)
d=(4,5)

def func1(a,b):
    return(a(0)*b(1))
```

Both of them give error `invalid syntax` or `'tuple' object is not callable`. Any help is appreciated. Please read it carefully before marking it "duplicate". Thank you.

Comment: You have to access tuple elements using square braces, i.e. `a[0]`, not `a(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First example is invalid python syntax. Second, index access uses square brackets.

```
def func1(a,b):
    return(a[0] * b[1])
```